# My Postgres always shutdown in a while (around 1 hour)

Tags: shutdown, services, postgresql

I have a problem about Postgres and Ubuntu VPS. My service always shutdown without no reason. Below is Postgres's log. Could anyone take a look at this situation please?

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is your server running GitLab?

Comment: No, I used Github. I installed Docker, Postgres, Nginx, Pm2 and Node

Comment: Perhaps a more complete description of the server will be required, then. PostgreSQL is one of the most reliable database engines currently out there, so things do not happen without a valid reason. The error log that you shared a picture of is generally seen when projects like GitLab are installed but not completely configured. Something on your machine may be facing a similar issue.